# Adding ripple effect to already custom button

Tags: android, android-studio, ripple

I'm trying to add ripple effect to a custom button. But the only solution I found is adding a background which I have already done for achieving rounded corners for that button. Now I want to add the ripple effect. This is how my button tag looks so far:

```
<Button
    android:text="PLAY"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
    android:onClick="gotomainpage"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />
```

Answer (score 6):

use this code in your button

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with that.No resource identifier found for attribute 'forground' in package 'android'

Answer (score 5):

Easy

**1. Creating an Ripple Drawable Contains the Backgound Shape**

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?colorControlHighlight">         //defaul ripple color

    <item>
        <shape                                //the background shape when it's not being click
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <corners
                android:radius="32dp" />

        </shape>

    </item>

</ripple>
```

**2. Applying the Drawable to the Button and REMOVE THE SHADOW**

```
<Button
    style="?borderlessButtonStyle"              //remove the default shadow
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/background_button"        //here
    android:text="Sign up"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a `android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"`

**drawable/ripple.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/ripple_white">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

if the `View` has a radius on its corners, apply this XML inside the shape (otherwise the ripple goes all the way to the corner);

```
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
```

if you want ripples that end up as circles then use this

**drawable/ripple_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/ripple_white">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

This method requires minimum API level 21 or later and `android:foreground` has no effect on API levels lower than 23